# Error POST con objetos en los parametros Python

Tags: python, api, rest, post

Tengo un servicio en `.net` el cual esta reciviendo mi petición `html` de forma correcta para variables con un único valor, pero cuando envío un objeto la petición se cae.

Mi función en Python es la siguiente:

```
def solicitarPedido(token, items):

    urlPedidos = "http://localhost:54192/api/Pedidos/"

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    productos = []

    for item in items:
        dic = {"cantidad": item.cantidad, "producto": {"idProducto": item.idProducto, "nombreProducto": item.nombre, "precioEstimado": item.precio, "imagenProducto": item.imagen}, "calidad": item.calidad}
        productos.append(dic)

    hoy = datetime.now()
    hoy = hoy.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

    data = {
        "token": str(token),
        "fechaPedido": hoy,
        "fechaEntrega": None,
        "pais": "Pais random",
        "ciudad": "Cuidad random",
        "direccionPedido": "calle random 1234",
        "detallePedido": productos,
     }

     response = requests.request("POST", urlPedidos, headers=headers, json = json.dumps(data))

     print("request", response.text.encode('utf8'))

     if(response.status_code == 200):
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

con postman la api funciona de forma correcta y el json que le estoy mandando es el siguiente:

```
{ "token":"7fc5bcb7-0495-4c23-9de3-35502388c41e", "fechaPedido": "2020-10-21T20: 24: 37", "fechaEntrega": null, "pais": "Chile", "ciudad": "Santiago", "direccionPedido": "calle random 1234", "detallePedido": [{"cantidad": "8","idProducto": "6","calidad": "premium"},{"cantidad": "10", "idProducto": "5","calidad": "premium"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El módulo `requests` proporciona directalmente una función concreta para el método post, esta es `requests.post(url, .....)`

```
def solicitarPedido(token, items):

    urlPedidos = "http://localhost:54192/api/Pedidos/"

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    productos = []

    for item in items:
        dic = {"cantidad": item.cantidad, "producto": {"idProducto": item.idProducto, "nombreProducto": item.nombre, "precioEstimado": item.precio, "imagenProducto": item.imagen}, "calidad": item.calidad}
        productos.append(dic)

    hoy = datetime.now()
    hoy = hoy.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

    data = {
        "token": str(token),
        "fechaPedido": hoy,
        "fechaEntrega": None,
        "pais": "Pais random",
        "ciudad": "Cuidad random",
        "direccionPedido": "calle random 1234",
        "detallePedido": productos,
     }

     response = requests.post(urlPedidos, headers=headers, json=data)

     print("request", response.text)

     return bool(response)
```

A partir de la pequeña mejora agregada con el llamado a la función `request.post`, hay varios aspectos más por mejorar/corregir.

1. El argumento json de la funcion `post` recibe un diccionario, no es necesario hacer la conversión del diccionario a una string que represente el json.
2. `response.text.encode('utf-8')` no es del todo correcto. Para recuperar el contenido de la respuesta tienes dos opciones:

   1. Propiedad `response.content`. Retorna el contenido(aveces nombrado payload) en su representación raw bytes.
   2. Propiedad `response.text`. Retorna el contenido codificado generalmente en `utf-8`. La codificación regresada generalmente es adivinada por la función a través de las cabeceras de la respuesta.

En conclusión, `response.text.encode('utf8')` lo único que esta haciendo es transformar el contenido de la respuesta a una representación raw bytes(es el mismo resultado que solo aplicar `response.content`). Generalmente(y lo que creo que quieres hacer) es tener un string normal que puedas usar dentro de tu programa y que contenga la respuesta, para ese caso basta con usar simplemente `response.text`.

3. Por último, el objeto `response` retornado por la petición tiene implementado el dunder method `__bool___`, esto signfica que al aplicar la función bool sobre este objeto este tiene un comportamiento definido, el comportamiento definido para este objeto es que si la respuesta tiene un valor estrictamente menor a 400 en su propiedad `status_code`, entonces retorna `True`, si el valor es mayor o igual a 400 entonces retorna `False`. Este comportamiento puede ser bien aprovechado en la mayoría de los casos, después de todo el status code 200 no es el único status code que determina que una acción ha sido exitosa.